# Which MIME Types can be displayed in browser

Tags: html, mime-types, mime

I'm writing an internal application to serve up files to consuming applications, and I'm trying to figure out which file types can be displayed in browser. 
As an Example: 
A .docx file cannot be displayed in browser (by default at least). If an attempt is made to display it, it would begin downloading it instead. 

On the other hand, a .pdf file can be displayed in browser. You can preview the contents and display it in an object tag or an iframe tag.

So I'm wondering if there's a list of mimetypes that can be displayed in browser, or if I'll have to experiment and continuously make changes as I figure out new ones that can or cannot be displayed.

For a little more information, primarily I'll be using Chrome for this as that's my companies primary web browser. I've looked around for awhile without anything, so I thought I'd ask here. 
I have looked at threads such as this one [While file types can be viewed in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860620/which-file-types-can-be-viewed-in-browser), but it doesn't really answer my question. 
Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Comment: "a .pdf file can be displayed in browser" - not by default. I doubt that there is a standard for **all** browsers

Answer (score 0):

The following list does not claim to be exhaustive:

```
application/atom+xml
application/javascript
application/json
application/pdf
application/rss+xml
application/xhtml+xml
application/xml

audio/mpeg
audio/ogg
audio/wav

font/woff
font/woff2

image/bmp
image/gif
image/jpeg
image/png
image/svg+xml
image/webp
image/x-icon

text/css
text/html
text/javascript
text/plain
text/xml

video/mp4
video/ogg
video/webm
```

Comment: Do you have any source that backs the claim that all of these content types can be used in all currently available browsers?

Comment: @NicoHaase No, I have no source that would back the claim other then using this mime types in my projects.

Comment: +1 There is not an exhaustive list (it varies), but this answer is the best I've seen. 
Note that while desktop and iOS browsers have supported PDF for a while, Chrome on mobile Android still does not :-(